# Can an HTML <script> fragment on the URL be used for XSS in a purely client side application?

Tags: javascript, html, http, security, xss

## Background

Say I have the following webpage:

```
<html>
  <script>
    document.write('querystring=' + location.search.substr(1));
  </script>
<html>
```

I open it at a URL like this:

```
http://completely-secure-site/?<script>alert('fsecurity')</script>
```

In all browsers tried (Chrome 57, Firefox 52 and Safari 10) the result is:

> querystring=%3Cscript%3Ealert(%27fsecurity%27)%3C/script%3E

Because angle brackets `<>` are [not valid URL characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1547899/which-characters-make-a-url-invalid/1547940#1547940) they seem to get automatically encoded by the browser on the way in, before they can get anywhere near the JS runtime.

## My assumption

This leads me to believe that simply **rendering the querystring directly on the client using `document.write` is always safe**, and not a possible XSS vector. (I realize that there are many other ways in which an app can be vulnerable of course, but let's stick to the precise case described here.)

## My question

Am I correct in this assumption?

- Is the inbound encoding of unsafe characters in the URL standardized / mandated across all reasonable browsers? (No possible XSS)
- Or, is this just a nicety / implementation detail of certain (modern?) clients on which I shouldn't rely globally? (XSS described above is theoretically possible)

---

<sub>Not relevant to the question, but an interesting aside. If I decode the URI first then browser behavior is different: `document.write(decodeURI(location.search.substr(1)));`. The [XSS Auditor](https://www.virtuesecurity.com/blog/understanding-xss-auditor/) in both Chrome and Safari blocks the page, while Firefox shows the alert.</sub>

Comment: Just in case you didn't know, there's a security.stackexchange that has deep experts in this stuff on it. Very helpful folks there.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If I use Query String `?<script>alert("d")</script>` on IE6 on Windows XP I get the injected code show the alert, this happens also using `decodeURI` or `decodeURIComponent` in the page, so I would say your second assumption is right if [IE6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_6) is still a reasonable browser: it is a feature of modern browsers

I also see Firefox 53 showing injected XSS alert when using the decode methods, Opera 44 & Chrome 57 (all on windows) block the code.

Answer (score 1):

According to [RFC 3986, section 2.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4) inbound encoding of unsafe characters **is** standardized. Although I recommend to not rely on that for two reasons:

- Not all browsers implement it
- There are so many browsers out in the wild which may do it another way accidentally or by intention.